# NS Lookup is not working

Tags: networking, dns, nslookup

I recently installed server 2012. Everything went alright but when I started to configure **DNS** this error came every time.

[image: NSLOOKUP Error Screen Shot]

As I don't know much about networking and there is no other resource in my office to look into this issue so I have to do this alone. If anyone of you can get me out of this issue it will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please check if you have created a **PTR(Pointer Record in DNS)** Section of Server Manager then Please **Uncheck IPv6** in Network Card's Properties Only enable IPv4 if you are not using IPv6.

Hope This will work for you :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Lemme get back to you after implementing what you've suggested.

Comment: I've implemented the suggestion. That helped me solve my problem. Thanks bro. :)